# Implementation of Collection and Iterator interface as inner class

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, collections, types

I'm trying to implement a Collection interface with Iterator as inner class. An ArrayCollection class that implements collection has a generic array (is it a correct way to say that class members are generic?).
[a screenshot from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVpPl.png)

```
public class ArrayCollection<T> implements Collection<T> {
private T[] m = (T[])new Object[10];
```

However when I'm implementing method next() for an Iterator interface I keep getting an Incompatible types error. However if make an ArrayIterator a non-generic class compiler doesn't have problems with array typecasting anymore.
[an error screenshot from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W03nR.png)

```
    private class ArrayIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private int cursor = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.cursor >= ArrayCollection.this.size();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
       return ArrayCollection.this.m[cursor++];
    }
}
```

So I have few questions:

1. How come the compiler can define the T[] m array type if I make an ArrayIterator non-generic?
2. Is it only the **inner classes** that implement/extend generic interfaces/classes can be non-generic?

Comment: Can you share the code here?

Comment: added code. There are also links screenshot from IDE. My stack overflow rating is too low to add images directly to the question.

Comment: never add images, add the code

Comment: Shouldn't the `hasNext()` method use `<`, instead of `>=`? --- You should also check that again in `next()` to correctly throw `NoSuchElementException` instead of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that will currently happen.

Answer (score 2):

You named your type variables similarly, `ArrayIterator<T>` has a different `T` than `ArrayCollection<T>`'s `T` is.

You can just remove the `<T>` from `ArrayIterator` (since it is a non-static inner class) and just have `Iterator` use the `T` from the parent class:

```
    private class ArrayIterator implements Iterator<T> {
```

This will fix the compile issue and your code.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, you are dealing with two different type variables. The outer class and the inner class each define a variable `T`, but they are not the same. There are several ways to solve this, one is to remove the T from the inner class declaration:

```
private class ArrayIterator implements Iterator<T> {
```

Now you are referencing the outer T only, without introducing a separate inner T

However, I would personally prefer to make the inner class static, in which case you can't use the outer type's variables. In this case you'd write

```
private static class ArrayIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
```

If you do this, you need to pass the type variable from the outer type to the inner:

```
return new ArrayIterator<T>();
```

The main difference is that a class that defines a type parameter shadows any existing type parameter of the same name, which leads to that strange error message.

Finally let me add that it's usually not a good idea to implement a Collection from scratch. Instead, you might want to extend `AbstractCollection` or `AbstractList`. This will let you focus on your core algorithm, but provide you with all the boilerplate methods for free.